# incron IN_MODIFY, IN_CLOSE_WRITE вызываются дважды при редактировании файла программой nano

Tags: linux, cron

Проблема такая: когда ставлю в incrone смотреть за изменением файлов, получается, что скрипт вызывается дважды, а если использовать IN_CLOSE_WRITE, то скрипт срабатывает на открытие файла и его закрытие, (если содержимое было изменено). 
Скрипт:

```
echo `date` >>/home/zsumo/serviceKPPO/test.txt
```

incrontab 1:

```
/home/zsumo/serviceKPPO/logError/ IN_CLOSE_WRITE /home/zsumo/serviceKPPO/noticeError.sh $#
```

incrontab 2:

```
/home/zsumo/serviceKPPO/logError/ IN_MODIFY /home/zsumo/serviceKPPO/noticeError.sh $#
```

Отмечу, что происходит двойное выполнения скрипта (IN_MODIFY) (IN_CLOSE_WRITE реагирует на открытие файла **nano** и на сохранение), если я пытаюсь вручную исправить файл, т.е.

```
nano /home/zsumo/serviceKPPO/logError/log1.log
```

Если же делать:

```
echo 123 > /home/zsumo/serviceKPPO/logError/log1.log
```

то все работает нормально.

Почему так происходит? Как я понял это из-за внутренних действий самого nano.

P.S. проверял **"vu"** там вообще все плохо.

Comment: сформулируйте, пожалуйста, сам **вопрос**. внести изменения можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> почему так происходит?

вероятно, это связано со спецификой работы программы (в данном случае — *nano*) с редактируемыми файлами.

подробности вы можете подсмотреть в исходниках программы, либо, чтобы составить беглое представление, воспользоваться программой, например, *strace*, примерно так:

```
$ strace -e open,close nano /home/zsumo/serviceKPPO/logError/log1.log
```

в *stderr* программа *strace* выдаст все обращения к системным вызовам *open* и *close*, которые осуществит трассируемая программа (*nano*).